# Don't Understand pycairo Decorator Example

Tags: python, python-decorators, pycairo

This is a complete example of pycairo running in a jupyter notebook from the github pycairo examples. It makes a figure of a circle that shows up as an inline figure in the notebook. My problem is that it looks to me like the code only defines functions and never runs them.

What am I missing?

```
import cairo
from IPython.display import Image, display
from math import pi
from io import BytesIO

def disp(draw_func):
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 200, 200)
    ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
    draw_func(ctx, 200, 200)
    with BytesIO() as fileobj:
        surface.write_to_png(fileobj)
        display(Image(fileobj.getvalue(), width=200))
@disp
def draw(cr, width, height):
    # cr.scale(width, height)
    cr.set_line_width(8)
    cr.arc(100, 100, 60, 0, 2 * pi)
    cr.stroke()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way that decorators work, the second definition is equivalent (modulo namespace pollution) to:

```
def temp(cr, width, height):
    # cr.scale(width, height)
    cr.set_line_width(8)
    cr.arc(100, 100, 60, 0, 2 * pi)
    cr.stroke()
draw = disp(temp)
```

so `disp` does get called and, through it, `draw`.

However, as `disp` returns `None`, I must confess I’m at loss to say what the point is. It looks like an abuse of the decorator mechanism, but maybe there’s some deeper sense in it that I am missing.